# How to avoid validator error for HTML script tag containing markup (in JavaScript template)

Tags: javascript, html, template-engine, w3c-validation

I came across a JavaSciprt templating system.

Here is a simple article : http://blog.reybango.com/2010/07/09/not-using-jquery-javascript-templates-youre-really-missing-out/

Digging in this topic, I found several other JavaScript template engines. However I haven't found any information how to deal with validation errors.

The errors I mean are: Using markup like what in the mentioned in the article cited above, I have an HTML fragment like this:

```
<script id="clientTemplate" type="text/html">
    <li><a href="clients/${id}">${name}</a></li>
</script>
```

When I check that with the validator, I get errors like `end tag for element A which is not open`, etc.

Is there a way to suppress those errors?

Comment: Which DOCTYPE are you validating against?